# Use geojson result file in leaflet

Tags: jquery, leaflet, geojson

I generate a geojson file from a query and I'd like to show results on my leaflet service.

Here is the current code which works for locally stored file :

```
$.getJSON("local_file",function(data){
L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});
```

What I'd like is to be able to pass the file as an url parameter (like http://mydomain.tld/maps/index.html?myfile.geojson or any other solution which will mark my maps with my query results.

Thank you

Comment: What server-side language do you use?

Comment: I can use PHP and HTML

Comment: I'm trying another approach with leaflet-ajax, now I use : 
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("./map.geojson").addTo(map);

Is it possible to replace "./map.geojson" with data's coming from a temporary generated (by php) geojson file ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working with leaflet.ajax.js :

```
var jsonLayer= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("query_json.php").addTo(map);
```

In `query_json.php` I make my connection to the DB and use the `json_encode($my_var)` jquery's function to echo the results.